# title size for charts.PerformanceSummary

Tags: r

I'm not 100% sure if this is just a bug or some other issue but how do you change the font size of the title for outputs of `charts.PerformanceSummary()` from the `PerformanceAnalytics` package?

Here is my reproducible example for what i would have hoped would have increased the font size by 6 times what it original was...

```
require(PerformanceAnalytics)
v <- rnorm(100,0.001,0.003)
charts.PerformanceSummary(xts(v,Sys.Date()-(100:1)),main="random title")
charts.PerformanceSummary(xts(v,Sys.Date()-(100:1)),main="random title", cex.main=6)
```

The outputs appear to be the same with no change in title size....

Comment: If SO isn't able to help you with this problem, you may also want to ask on the R-sig-finance mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

Set `cex.main` before you plot:

```
par(cex.main = 6)
charts.PerformanceSummary(xts(v,Sys.Date()-(100:1)),main="random title")
```

#### Update

Another alternative that you might try (but one which requires a bit of testing first) is to use the `title()` function.

```
# Set `main` to `""`
charts.PerformanceSummary(xts(v,Sys.Date()-(100:1)), main = "")
# You'll have to experiment with the best combination of `line` and `cex.main`
title(main="random title", line = -2, outer = TRUE, cex.main=3)
```

Comment: cool! but is there anyway to do it in the code charts.PerformanceSummary line instead? as I dont particularly want to have to keep changing cex.main back to defaults and then remembering to readjust before running the charts.PerformanceSummary command...

Comment: @h.l.m, not as far as I can see. See my update for another alternative. You can probably re-write your own `charts.PerformanceSummary()` to allow for your modifications though. See, for example, [this blog post](http://timelyportfolio.blogspot.in/2011/09/reporting-good-enough-to-share.html). (They hard-coded the values for `cex`, but it's easy enough to add those to your function.